# Select just the parent of a selected div with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to select just one div, exacly the parent of a selected div but no success... my code selects all divs above the selected one, It's wrong, how can I do it the right way? 
I wanna implement a simple search behavior...

```
<script>**$(".emoticons-row").hide();**</script>
<div class="emoticons-row">
    <div class="emoticons-col emoticon"><img title="Smile" src="./images/smile.png" alt="Smile"></div>
    <div class="emoticons-col emoticon">:)</div>
    <div class="emoticons-col desc">Smile, Smiling</div>
    <script>**$(".desc:contains('Sorriso')").parent().show();**</script>
    <div class="emoticons-col action"><input type="button" value="copy" /></div>
</div>
<div class="emoticons-row">
    <div class="emoticons-col emoticon"><img title="Sad" src="./images/sad.png" alt="Sad"></div>
    <div class="emoticons-col emoticon">:(</div>
    <div class="emoticons-col desc">Sad</div>
    <div class="emoticons-col action"><input type="button" value="copy" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: $(".desc:contains('Smile')").parent().show(); // I forgot a word in portuguese when posting it here.

Comment: $("target-div").closest('*');

Comment: It doesn't work. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".emoticons-row").hide();
  $(".desc:contains('Smile')").parents("div.emoticons-row").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emoticons-row">
  <div class="emoticons-col emoticon">
    <img title="Smile" src="./images/smile.png" alt="Smile">
  </div>
  <div class="emoticons-col emoticon">:)</div>
  <div class="emoticons-col desc">Smile, Smiling</div>
  <div class="emoticons-col action">
    <input type="button" value="copy" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="emoticons-row">
  <div class="emoticons-col emoticon">
    <img title="Sad" src="./images/sad.png" alt="Sad">
  </div>
  <div class="emoticons-col emoticon">:(</div>
  <div class="emoticons-col desc">Sad</div>
  <div class="emoticons-col action">
    <input type="button" value="copy" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this fiddle here : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/yLug76p6/25/)

You can use the .parents('div.emoticons-row') method to find a particular parent among all parents of a div.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please go ahead and accept one of the answers that have been posted.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click handler to the child element and target its parent:

```
$( ".emoticons-col" ).on( "click", function() {
 var target = $(this).parent(); //This is the ref to the parent of the row you clicked
 target.hide(); //hide the parent and it's children
});
```

It wont matter what child you click, it will always assign the parent div to a "target" var that you can do whatever you need with. The Target var in this case is reference to the parent div. If you click any child, it will hide the parent and its children on click.

Comment: Very good, but my question is simpler than your solution, but thank you for your insight =).

Comment: Fair enough. Hope you find the answer you are looking for and good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Casey, you can use `closest` method of jQuery to do this:

```
$(".desc:contains('Smile')").closest(".emoticons-row");
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Sorry. Take a look at the stark's solution.